# C# Translating an Input

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder

I have a WinForm with 2 TextBoxes in the first one I have the user input, the input shall have to be translated with this Method, if I click a Button, and give it out in the second TextBox.

```
public static string Translate(string text)
{
    var from = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var to = "jkhinolmrspqvwtuzGbcJafgde";
    var ret = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var l in text)
    {
        int index;
        for (index = 0; index <= from.Length; index++)
            if (index == from.Length || from[index] == l)
               break;
        ret.Append(index != from.Length ? to[index] : l);
    }
    return ret.ToString();
}
```

I just don't know how I can use this in a winForm with an UserInput an give the output in the second TextBox.

Comment: `String.IndexOf` would probably help you a lot.

Comment: Instead of your inner for-loop, try using `IndexOf` to get the index of the specific character in the `from` string.  Then use the array-subscript notion of `to` with the value returned from `IndexOf` to get the translated character.

Comment: Also worth to know that there's cleaner way for this task like this: `public string Reverse(string text)
{
   if (text == null) return null;

   char[] array = text.ToCharArray();
   Array.Reverse(array);
   return new String(array);
}`

Comment: Well my main Problem is, how to get this in my Second Textbox if i Klick the translate Button. I know it's the easiest of all but.. i dunno how to make this.

Comment: Got it, i just switch something wrong :x Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

> I just dunno how i can use this in a winForm with an UserInput an give
>   the output in the second TextBox

Assuming your function works... do this:

```
textbox2.Text = Translate(textbox1.Text);
```

It would be nicer to wrap this in a try/catch block.

Comment: Well, didnt expect that is that easy, thanks mate! Now i just have to make this work.It just deletes the text in 1.Textbox and does nothing.

Comment: The above should probably be `textbox2.Text = Translate(textbox1.Text);`, assuming that your text boxes are called `textbox1` and `textbox2`. Also, you need to put that line somewhere sensible (e.g. in the click event handler for a button, so that when the user clicks the button the text of the second text box is updated).

Comment: Yes, fixed it i just messed the TextBox1 and TextBox2 things off. Thank you all!